# Minecart with hopper doesn't collect items

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-redstone

I'm new to redstone devices and I'm trying to make a sugar cane farm. I already solved some problems I had with the Observer and powered rails but not I just need to fix one more issue.

My **Minecart with Hopper** is not collecting items when it passes by them. Please see image:

[image: Sugar cane farm with auto moving collecting cart]

Any help how to solve this ?

I have Minecraft Bedrock edition v1.17.34

Comment: It looks like your minecart runs in front of the blocks where the sugarcane is planted? Idk if this is how it HAS to be, but whenever I use a minecart with a hopper I always have the track run under the blocks where the sugarcane is planted. It can pick up objects through a block. Im not really sure it can pick them up the way  you have it.

Comment: Yes, at the moment is running right in front of the grass blocks. I tried underneath also and it didn't work either! :(

Answer (score 3):

A hopper minecart cannot collect items that are on the rail.
You’ll need to have the items fall in from the top, like so:

[image: Like this]

With the result of:

[image: with this outcome]

Hope this helped!